# Laplace operator. Wave equation.

Tags: wave-equation

Why does Laplace operator affect only x-coordinates but not time variable in wave equation. Does `t` variable in `U(X, t)` is different from `x` coordinates? I think they are equal.

Comment: The gradient measures rates of change with respect to spatial position, where a point actually is in space, and the Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient. Time is not a spatial coordinate. If it were, we wouldn't have to ask where _and_ when when meeting somebody, only where.

Comment: It's kinda common explanation, could you please give something more strict?

Comment: Oops my brain decided to talk about Fourier transforms but you want Laplace. The simplest reason is probably that your boundary conditions are on $x$, not $t$ so the boundary terms with the Laplace transform don't work out nicely.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the derivation of the wave equation (for instance a physical derivation from a physics or engineering textbook). Otherwise, from a purely mathematical perspective, the answer is: Because that is the definition of the wave operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often when solving ODE or PDE with Laplace transform (in undergraduate courses), it is about the one-dimensional Laplace transform. In your case, the $t$ is considered constant (a snapshot in time) when we "squeeze" the space $x$ exponentially.

Indeed, $t$ (time) and $x$ (space) are in equal standing mathematically in terms of Laplace transform. You can actually do the Laplace transform on $t$ with $x$ unaffected.

There's of course [multi-dimensional Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_transform#Multidimensional_Laplace_transform) that affects more than one variable when operated.